# VIM with Python2&3 Support

Tags: python, vim, centos7

Open VIM and run command:

```
:python print "Hello World!"
```

but failed with:

```
E448: Could not load library function _PyArg_Parse_SizeT                                                 
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
```

My environment below:

- OS: CentOS 7.3
- Python2.7.13 Install:

  ```
  wget -c https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/Python-2.7.13.tgz
  tar -zxvf Python-2.7.13.tgz
  cd Python-2.7.13
  ./configure
  make
  make install
  ```
- Python3.6.1 Install:

  ```
  wget -c https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tgz
  tar -zxvf Python-3.6.1.tgz
  cd Python-3.6.1/
  ./configure
  make
  make install
  ```
- VIM8.0 Install:

  ```
  rpm -e $(rpm -qa | grep vim) --nodeps
  git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
  cd vim/src
  ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/ --enable-python3interp --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/ --enable-multibyte --enable-cscope --enable-gui=auto --enable-xim --with-x --enable-fontset --disable-selinux
  make
  make install
  vim --version | grep python
  ```
- other

  ```
  echo "alias vi='vim'" >> ~/.bashrc
  echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:\$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
  source ~/.bashrc
  ```

Comment: You forgot the output of `$ vim --version | grep python`.

Comment: [root@devops ~]# vim --version | grep python

`+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +wildignore`

Comment: @romainl
vim with both supports(python/dyn and python3/dyn)